# Hadith: Deeds Judged by Intentions

Tags: hadith

> [Sahih al-Bukhari 1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1)
>
> Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab: I heard Allah's Messenger saying: The
> reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get
> the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for
> worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what
> he emigrated for.

Is there an authentic hadith, as to the story behind who the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) refers to when he mentions someone migrating for a woman? (To my limited knowledge, the man migrated—or, rather, his primary motivation was—because the woman he wanted to marry wanted him to come to Madine.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a hadith compiled by at-Tabarani and others which ibn Hajar mentioned as the reason for adding this information stating that a man went out and emigrated because of a woman called Umm Qais.